# MongoDB Collection runCommand from PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this [example](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/40513621310/mongodb-text-search-experimental-feature-in-mongodb).

```
db.Wall.runCommand( "text", { search : "See" } );
```

How to call this from PHP? I can't find the method in `MongoCollection` class,

Note I'm running mongo 2.4 dev version.

I tried to use the command method  with no luck Collection called Wall

```
$ret = $db->command( array(
                        "runCommand" => "Wall",
                        "text" => array('search' => $text))
                    );
```

The output was

```
Array ( [ok] => 0 [errmsg] => no such cmd: runCommand [bad cmd] => Array ( [runCommand] => Wall [text] => Array ( [search] => See ) ) )
```

I found the Answer but I need to wait 7 hrs because my reputation is LOW :)

```
$ret = $db->command( array(
                        "text" => "Wall",
                        "search" => $text)
                    );
```

Comment: Just post the answer as the answer, you can tick your own answer in 2 days and it will help everyone who comes to this question. Putting at the end of the question makes it harder to find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a more extensive example of Mongo Text Search usage in PHP

```
<?php

$m = new MongoClient(); // connect
$db = $collection = $m->foo; // get the database named "foo"
$collection = $db->bar; // get the collection "bar" from database named "foo"

$collection->ensureIndex(
    array(
        'title' => 'text',
        'desc' => 'text',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'ExampleTextIndex',
        'weights' => array(
            'title' => 100,
            'desc' => 30,
        ),
        'timeout' => 60000000
    )
);

$result = $db->command(
    array(
        'text' => 'bar', //this is the name of the collection where we are searching
        'search' => 'hotel', //the string to search
        'limit' => 5, //the number of results, by default is 1000
        'project' => Array( //the fields to retrieve from db
            'title' => 1
        )
    )
); 

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ret = $db->command( array(
                        "text" => "Wall",
                        "search" => $text)
                    );
```