# How to search in fulltext index using php in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using mongodb 2.4 and added fulltext index to the "title" field in one the collection. How should I search something in that field using php?

This is the code I use right now:

```
$params = array(
        '_id' => array(
            '$gt' => (int)$gt
        )
    );
$r = $this->collection->find( $params )->limit($limit);
```

Comment: link one on a google search: http://blog.mongohq.com/blog/2013/01/22/first-week-with-mongodb-2-dot-4-development-release/

Comment: Might be duplicate question: Here's an example:[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313805/mongodb-collection-runcommand-from-php)

Comment: @Dagon That link doesn't mention `PHP` at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be the answer to my question:

```
<?php
$result = $db->command(
    array(
        'text' => 'bar', //this is the name of the collection where we are searching
        'search' => 'hotel', //the string to search
        'limit' => 5, //the number of results, by default is 1000
        'project' => Array( //the fields to retrieve from db
            'title' => 1
        )
    )
);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php#111891

Comment: I got result like string(21) "no such command: text" text is not taking as collection