# MongoDB full text search using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

It seems that my searching for how to do this brings back results that are a year old and apparently no longer work or I am not doing something correctly.

Through the MongoDB command line, I have run this for indexing:

db.collectiontest.ensureIndex( { "$**": "text" }, { name: "TextIndex" } )

Did this based on the example at

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/

I do not receive an error when that is executed.

Here are 2 of the Stackoverflow postings I have tried:

[How to search in fulltext index using php in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070957/how-to-search-in-fulltext-index-using-php-in-mongodb)

[MongoDB Collection runCommand from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313805/mongodb-collection-runcommand-from-php)

The last post, I tried the accepted answer except the ensure index since I did that via command line and the poster's solution as well. Both methods returns a message showing "Array ( [errmsg] => no such cmd: text [bad cmd] =>" .

I'm running a vm of Ubuntu Server 12 with latest release versions of PHP and MongoDB.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of mongodb, the correct syntax is

```
db.collection.ensureIndex(
                           {
                             subject: "text",
                             content: "text"
                           }
                         )
```

for indexing multiple text fields in a single collection, and

```
 db.collection.ensureIndex(
                               {
                                 content: "text"
                               }
                             )
```

for a single field. Try modifying your ensureIndex() call to match one of the above patterns and see if that works for you.

The correct query syntax can be found here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

```
db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "coffee" } } )
```

Comment: jpsf: Thank you again for responding to one of my questions. I must correct myself in that I had to check to make sure I am using the current version of mongoDB (the project has a couple a of different test servers setup).

I am experiencing a different problem when trying to index:



 "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
 "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "language override unsupported: Latin",
 "code" : 17262

The data is for transcripts (mostly medieval) and the languages are varied. The collection has a field for "language" but an entry could have multiple values for it.

Comment: Also, my client may also have to just choose the specific fields that could be part of a general search instead of all fields queried. Thanks, James

Comment: here's the list of languages mongodb supports as of v2.6 in text search: 
    da or danish
    nl or dutch
    en or english
    fi or finnish
    fr or french
    de or german
    hu or hungarian
    it or italian
    no or norwegian
    pt or portuguese
    ro or romanian
    ru or russian
    es or spanish
    sv or swedish
    tr or turkish

Comment: @jspf :  I marked your answer as that would be the correct way although my problem may be due to the languages supported. Appreciate you listing the current languages supported by MongoDB at this time. Again, thank you for taking the time to answer my question.